# How to pass parameters to logrotate file?

Tags: linux, logrotate

I am new to Linux env. I got task that how to pass parameters to logrotate configuration file. E.x Size `<<dynamic value>>` instead of static configuration like Size 3.

Either passing param values to logrotate OR reading from config also fine.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Did you have a look at the predefined configuration files locate (usually) in /etc/logrotate.d ? I'm pretty sure some of them might help you understand how to trigger file rotation.

Comment: I have cleaned up your question a bit, but you need to specify what you are trying to do.  Where do these dynamic values come from?  Why can't you just write your logrotate configuration from your program?

Comment: We are calling from external like callExternalScript "LOGROTATE" "$LOG_ROTATE_SCRIPT $LOG_ROTATE_PROP"